# Passing JSON String as value to a Spring data REST endpoint

Tags: json, spring, spring-data-rest

I want to store a string, which contains valid JSON, in a database column. 
The access is done via @RepositoryRestResource. So if I want to change the value of the column, the request will be in JSON format including the column name and the new value. I wanted to write a testcase for this scenario using MockMvc, send a PATCH request to the endpoint and wait for the response.

I tried to escape the value part with quotation marks

At first I have a method, which builds the JSON request body:

```
private String tableConfig() {
    return "{\n" +
        "\"tableConfig\" : " + "\"[\n"
        + "\"listOfProperties\" : [\n"
        + "\"aBooleanProperty\" : true,\n"
        + "\"anIntProperty\" : 5,\n"
        + "\"aStringProperty\" : \"stringValue\""
        + "]"
        + "]\"" +
        "}";
  }
```

Next there is the test case:

```
@Test
  public void testUpdateTableConfig() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(
        patch("http://localhost/api/usersettings/" + myEntity.getId())
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .characterEncoding("UTF-8")
            .content(tableConfig())
    )
        .andExpect(status().isNoContent())
        .andReturn();
  }
```

I expect to get no content response. Instead I get a 400 Bad request, so I assume Spring tries to map the JSON value within the string to an object tree or something like that. 
Is there a way to pass a JSON request, which contains JSON as value and get the raw JSON data into a String via Spring Data Rest?

Edit: Added the URL as requested

Comment: Could you add your *<URL-to-the-Rest-Repository-Resource>* endpoint implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json is invalid.
Actual table config value is

```
{
"tableConfig" : "[
"listOfProperties" : [
"aBooleanProperty" : true,
"anIntProperty" : 5,
"aStringProperty" : "stringValue"]]"}
```

I think it should be like below

```
{
   "tableConfig":[
      {
         "listOfProperties":{
            "aBooleanProperty":true,
            "anIntProperty":5,
            "aStringProperty":"stringValue"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

or

```
{
   "tableConfig":{
      "listOfProperties":{
         "aBooleanProperty":true,
         "anIntProperty":5,
         "aStringProperty":"stringValue"
      }
   }
}
```

you can validate it on online json validator.

I suggest to use Json library Gson or Jackson.

Comment: Ok I can try to rework the escapings, but note that what I want is: 
The value for "tableConfig" should be a string containing JSON and it should be stored as is in the column.
With your solution, I might trigger the JacksonMapper from Spring, to map this JSON into something else. I want the raw JSON to be stored in the DB.

Comment: Yes, I see. you need to check " escape first. And as ListOfProperties has key value pairs, it should be [] or object list [ { key-value pairs} ].
Your request header contains "Content-Type: application/json", Spring tries to check validation of Json and return 400 error(Bad request). You also need to check controller part.

Comment: Thanks. The escaping was wrong, I had to escape the \ too.